# Convert a column values to column names SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with below schema. Would like to get results as in expected result in SQL server. Pivot does not work as Value column is string. Please suggest efficient way to achieve this. Thanks!

Table:

```
 Dim Key(String) , Dim Value (String)
   AB                XY1 
   AB                XY2
   CD                XY3
   CD                XY4
```

Expected Result

```
New columns=>  AB      CD
Row values =>  XY1     XY3
               XY2     XY4
```

Comment: Why is `XY1` on the same row as `XY3` and not `XY4`?   Why do you think you cannot PIVOT when the value is a string?

Comment: Are AB and CD the new column names?

Comment: how do you know what ab goes with what cd -- do you have another index columns?

Comment: @SeanLange Yes AB & CD are new column names.

Comment: Normally, the input to a pivot operations requires three dimensions  (columns, fields, attributes).  One which will be the X-axis in the pivot table,  a second which will be the Y-axis in the pivot table,  and a third which will be converted to a measure, and go into the value at the intersection of one column and one row in the pivot.  Measures, usually called aggregates, can be sum, average, min, max, and a few others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `row_number()` :

```
select max(case when key = 'ab' then Value end) as ab, 
       max(case when key = 'cd' then Value end) as cd
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by key order by Value) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by seq;
```

However, your `pivot` version should also work with `row_number()`.

**EDIT :**

```
select tt.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by [key] order by Value) as seq
      from table t
     ) as t pivot 
     ( max(value) for [key] in ([ab], [cd]) 
     ) tt;
```

Comment: This assumes the 2nd column (which is called value in his question) order is how you match items.   Seems a big assumption

Comment: @Hogan. . .  No, it is actually `key` is important here. If the keys are very unknown then `OP` may need `Dynamic SQL` instead .

Comment: Thanks @YogeshSharma. It works. Can you point out how to do this in Pivot , because Pivot expects aggregate functions. So row_number() partition sequence needs to be used correct as Min or Max correct?

Comment: I would suggest NOT using a pivot. This conditional aggregation is simpler to code and understand. It also has a slight performance benefit over pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Self join should work. However you did not provide the complete business requirements for the SQL.

Which result do you expect?

```
New columns=>  AB      CD
Row values =>  XY1     XY3
               XY2     XY4
```

Or,

```
New columns=>  AB      CD
Row values =>  XY1     XY4
               XY2     XY3
```

Or,

```
New columns=>  AB      CD
Row values =>  XY1     
               XY2     
                       XY3
                       XY4
```

Your SQL would look like this,

```
select ab.value as "AB", cd.value as "CD"
from (select * from t where key='ab') ab
    ,(select * from t where key='cd') cd
```

But the above SQL gives you this result,

```
New columns=>  AB      CD
Row values =>  XY1    XY3 
               XY2    XY3 
               XY1    XY4  
               XY2    XY4
```

You should make a little modification the SQL to your needs. Hope it help!